# Cannot invoke a locally running lambda from another locally running application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-framework-offline

I have a `sails.js` backend application and a `serverless lambda` function. Both are running in the local machine for development purposes, I want to `invoke` the local running lambda function from the `sails.js` application, I can use `aws-sdk` in the sails application, but could it work? Is there any way that I can invoke the local lambda from another locally running application?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with serverless-offline plugin. It's pretty well described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline#usage-with-invoke